# python argparse: parameter=value

Tags: python-2.7

I am having little difficulty with argparse, and I would appreciate if somebody could advise on following two problems:

1)
my script takes several commnad line arguments, one of them is --color. I would like argparse to enforce the following syntax: --color=True and not tolerate syntax such as: --color True.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--color', nargs=1, default=True)
```

2)
Another option I am using is -i

```
parser.add_argument('-i','--ignorecase', action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

depending whether True or False,  re.compile will use flags=re.IGNORECASE or flags=0

```
if (args.ignorecase == True):

   CASE_SENSITIVITY=re.IGNORECASE
else:

   CASE_SENSITIVITY=0

pattern = re.compile('my_pattern', flags=CASE_SENSITIVITY)
```

is there any simpler way to assign the value to CASE_SENSITIVITY ? Perhaps inside the parser.add_argument, so that I can avoid the multiple steps, if else, and so on ?

Answer (score 1):

You could always use a ternary operator such as:

```
CASE_SENSITIVITY = 0 if not args.ignorecase else re.IGNORECASE
```